# Using Casts in a NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nspredicate

I have a class member "total" which is of type int. I am using "total" as an attribute in my predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"total ==%i", [searchText intValue]];
```

This predicate is used to collect matches when a search is executed. The predicate compares the user's search value, stored in iVar `searchText` , of type text with attribute "total" which is of type int.

I am able to check for equality easily like this:

```
 NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"total ==%i", [searchText  intValue]];
```

I would now like to make the predicate more robust and work like a text search so if a user types "5" into the search box, the predicate will return 5,52,550,etc.

In other words, I would like to treat "total", which is an attribute, as a string in my predicate filter so I can use **BEGINSWITH or CONTAINS**.

My problem is that the attribute "total" is of type int, not a string so I am stuck.

Here is my intent (pseudo code)

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"[total stringValue] BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];
```

Or

```
  NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"CAST(total, 'NSString' ) BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];
```

How can I do this without creating a string type in my class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d"]` is how you convert something from an integer into a string. You can just put it inline with your predicate declaration.

As for how to do it

> without creating a string type

I'm confused as to how you would use something as a string without creating a string.

Your predicate should look like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                          @"(content BEGINSWITH[c] %@)", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total]];
```

Comment: What am I missing? This results in a parsing error: NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"[NSString stringWithFormat:@\"%f\",total] BEGINSWITH %@", searchText];

Comment: thank you very much , Dustin however "total" does not have an explicit assignable value so I cannot use a format specifier.  "total" is the name of the  class member to be used in the predicate criteria. Need to alter this such that "total" is treated as a string: NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"total = %i", [searchText  intValue]];

Comment: You need to add some detail to your question; what is this `searchText` variable and why are you using its int value? Also you should be using `==` if you're checking for equality.

Comment: Dustin, I edited my question and added more details. According to the Predicate Prgramming Guide "==" and "=" are interchangeable. Both operators return an accurate result when comparing numbers for equality. I do agree that == is a better choice, though

Answer (score 0):

One (somewhat gross) way you could do this is to generate a predicate like:

```
total == %d OR total / 10 == %d OR total / 100 == %d OR total / 1000 == %d...
```

Assuming you know a small maximum value total could have.